# Why is the calculated field I created not using the the formula provided to return result

Tags: excel, pivot-table, calculated-field

These are the screenshots of me creating a calculated field, then the result I expected, and the one I got, which is not the result its supposed to give based on the formula I gave.

[Screenshot of me creating the calculated field to subtract the two columns on the pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLp23.png),

[Screenshot of the result I was expecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNjv9.png),

[Screenshot of the result I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKDHh.png)

Comment: Please, checkout the screenshots of the created calculated field, the result I expected, and the one I got. And also the way "sum" was added to the calculated fields name after I created it. @JosWoolley

Comment: Can you check your last two screenshots? They appear to be identical.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in my comment to your previous post on this issue, by default, *Calculated Fields* **always** apply a `SUM` aggregation to the values in the columns referenced **prior** to applying the aggregation you specify.

Effectively, this means that the `AVERAGE` functions you are using within the *Calculated Fields* are being applied to a **single value only**. So your *Sum of Average profit* column will be the result of

`AVERAGE(Sum of Box Office Revenue) - AVERAGE(Sum of Budget)`

where *Sum of Box Office Revenue* and *Sum of Budget* will be single values.

You can easily verify this by adding *Sum of Box Office Revenue* and *Sum of Budget* to your current Pivot Table and noting the difference between the two.

As mentioned, this is default behaviour for *Calculated Fields*, as non-intuitive as it may seem. To obtain what you require, you can either add your table to the `Data Model` and use a *measure* within `Power Pivot`, or else add an extra, 'dummy' column to your table which comprises the number 1 in every row, after which your *Calculated Field* formula would be:

`='Box Office Revenue'/Dummy - Budget/Dummy`

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much. 
Please, another question related to this. I found out that in the “show value as” tab after right clicking on the calculated field in the values box, the default option is “no calculation”, when I searched, I found out that it means “custom calculation is off” , I further searched how to turn it on, and I saw that there is supposed to be an option that says “ use this calculation “ option , but it isn’t there. Is it normal for it to be on the “no calculation” option ? Or is there a need for change, if there is, how do I go about that, please? 
@JosWoolley

Comment: Changing 'Show Values As' won't help you in this case, I'm afraid. And yes, it always defaults to 'No Calculation' until changed by the user.