# subtract two column pivot table using calculated value

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table, subtraction, calculated-field

I need to find the average of profit by subtracting ( **average budget from average  revenue** ) , both these two column calculated by pivot table 
[image]

I tried to input this in the calculated field:
 `=AVERAGE('Box Office Revenue ($)')-AVERAGE('Budget ($)')` 
and then summarized field value to **Average** but still show summation.
i don't need to subtract the summation of these two column but i need to subtract the averages.

Can you please support in that.

Comment: I answered this precise question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75236298/why-is-the-calculated-field-i-created-not-using-the-the-formula-provided-to-retu/75254566#comment132805972_75254566).

Comment: it works in google sheets only while could not do it in MS Excel